# How to check if statements dynamically

Tags: c#, sql, .net, if-statement

My questions as follows, I need to check conditions through the database. which means in the simple application we check if conditions like this.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your age");
    var age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());

    if (5 <= age && age <= 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Range 5 - 10");
    }else if (11 <= age && age <= 20)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Range 11 - 20");
    }
    else if (21 <= age && age <= 30)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Range 21 - 30");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Over range");
    }
}
```

Suppose, Client, needs to change the condition dynamically, which means he need to add additional condition to the system like,

`if 31 <= age && age <= 40` **=>** Range 31 - 40

When doing this in the client side, sometimes wrong conditions can be added to the system like,

`(4 <= age && age <= 15)` this condition cannot be added, because the system already have condition `(5 <= age && age <= 10)`. When age is 7, both conditions will be true. like this type situations what is the best thing to do.

I need to store the conditions in my database,(PS:database table structure can be changed according to your answer)

as the sample table structure

```
ConditionID    Condition                  Details

con001         5 <= age && age <= 10      Range 5 - 10
con002         11 <= age && age <= 20     Range 11 - 20
con003         21 <= age && age <= 30     Range 21 - 30
```

Please give me a solution to solve this. How can I do this with C# and oracle SQL

Comment: Where do you want to handle this code side or db side?

Comment: @DipteeHamdapurkar Both side ok, but I think code side would be best. But DB side also fine if you can

Comment: You're building a rules engine. You may not think that's what you're doing, but if you want a routine to validate dynamically created conditions then you're starting on that journey. So this would be a good point to check whether this is something you want to do, and if so whether you would be better off using an existing rules engine rather than rolling your own from scratch.

Comment: @APC Can you please give a sample code to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly you don't need to store the `Details` as a column, since you can build it in a dynamic way later in your code. And secondly you don't need to store the `Condition` as a string column also, because it makes your work more complicated when you want to parse it as conditions in your C# code. All you need is, storing two integer values in your database as `Lower` and `Upper` values of your ranges and make `ConditionID` identity. Your table should be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblConditions] (
[ConditionID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Lower]       INT NOT NULL,
[Upper]       INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ConditionID] ASC)
);
```

And then you can write something like this in your code:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"Enter your age");
var age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());

using (var db = new forTestEntities())
{
    var result = db.tblConditions.Where(c => c.Lower <= age && age <= c.Upper).AsEnumerable()
        .Select(c => $"Range {c.Lower} - {c.Upper}")
        .DefaultIfEmpty("Over range").SingleOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

**EDIT**: If you are not familiar with this `$` operator, it is called [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) and it is available in C# 6+, if you are using the older version of C# you can use `string.Format` like this:

```
c => string.Format("Range {0} - {1}", c.Lower, c.Upper)
```

Also to add dynamic condition to the database you can use the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"Enter Lower");
var lower = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());

Console.WriteLine(@"Enter Upper");
var upper = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());

using (var db = new forTestEntities())
{
    var newCondition = new tblCondition
    {
        Lower = lower,
        Upper = upper
    };

    var range = Enumerable.Range(newCondition.Lower, 
                            newCondition.Upper - newCondition.Lower + 1);

    var check = db.tblConditions.AsEnumerable().Any(c => range
                .Intersect(Enumerable.Range(c.Lower, c.Upper - c.Lower + 1)).Any());

    if (!check)
    {
        db.tblConditions.Add(newCondition);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Please note: I have used SQL Server and Entity Framework-DB First approach, you can change it as per your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have not tried this yet. can you please tell me, when the table contains `Lower = 5 & Upper = 10`  the user cannot include this value to db, such as  `Lower = 3 & Upper = 12` because, as an example when the age = 8 both condition will be through. can I prevent this using your code?

Comment: @Sachith You're Welcome. I have already checked for that and included that validation also. Check this lines: `var range = Enumerable.Range(newCondition.Lower, 
                            newCondition.Upper - newCondition.Lower + 1);

    var check = db.tblConditions.AsEnumerable().Any(c => range
                .Intersect(Enumerable.Range(c.Lower, c.Upper - c.Lower + 1)).Any());`

Comment: @Sachith I have used `Intersect` for this kind of validations.

Comment: you're awesome :) thank you very much. I'll try this and accept your answer immediately +1 :) Hope I can do this using Oracle too ;)

Comment: The code works fine. thanks, bro :) I here you used VS2017? I tested with this using VS2013. when using this code in VS2013 `.Select(c => $"Range {c.Lower} - {c.Upper}")` this line makes error. the problem was **$**. So I removed it. but after remove it output shows as `Range {c.Lower} - {c.Upper}`. how to avoid that. Can I do this in Oracle? hope it's not making any error :) Thanks again

Comment: If you can please explain the following code lines. I haven't any idea about those lines. please explain me that logic :)

`var range = Enumerable.Range(newCondition.Lower, newCondition.Upper - newCondition.Lower + 1); var check = db.tblConditions.AsEnumerable().Any(c => range .Intersect(Enumerable.Range(c.Lower, c.Upper - c.Lower + 1)).Any());`

Comment: @Sachith Check my updated answer about `$` operator. `Enumerable.Range` generates a sequence of numbers from lower to upper and then checks for any intersect with client' entered data and it repeats for all rows in your database and checks for intersect and if it didn't find any, it means you are allowed to add new entries to your DB.

Comment: And I also like to know, what do you do inside `Enumerable.Range` in both lines?

Comment: @Sachith Check this link to know how does `Enumerable.Range` works. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you, sir, Thank you very much for your responses & effort

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do much more than store a list of numbers to make this work. Try something like this:

```
var ages = new [] { 5, 10, 20, 30 };

var limits = ages.Zip(ages.Skip(1), (a0, a1) => new
{
    lower = a0,
    upper = a1,
    message = $"Range {a0} - {a1}"
});

var age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
var message =
    limits
        .Where(l => l.lower <= age && l.upper >= age)
        .Select(l => l.message)
        .DefaultIfEmpty("Over range")
        .First();

Console.WriteLine(message);
```

If I run it and enter `25` the message `"Range 20 - 25"` comes out.